# Search Functionality RunTime error 424 at Select

Tags: ms-access, vba

My requirement: To search for data in database, using VB forms and 3 text boxes.

1 TextBox, I will give Input (UserName)
1 TextBox for Location
1 TextBox for displaying output

**My code is**

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection '* Connection String

Dim oCm As ADODB.Command '* Command Object

Dim sName As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim uname As String
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\test2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Cn.ConnectionTimeout = 40
Cn.Open
Set oCm = New ADODB.Command
oCm.ActiveConnection = Cn

‘Record Set
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

‘Select Operation
rs.Open "SampleTable", Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable

uname = rs("UserName")

rs.Open "Select * from SampleTable where uname = '" & text1.Text & "'", ActiveConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

**'Display the Output in TextBox3**
TextBox3.Text = rs("UserName") + rs("Location")

rs.Close
Cn.Close
End Sub
```

I can understand the population of data is not happening so getting a RunTime error 424 at Select statement. How can I retrieve the data for the corresponding Input given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not need to open the table; `rs.Open "SampleTable"` before searching it.
2. Not sure what this is for; `uname = rs("UserName")`
3. You should just run; `rs.Open "Select * ...` (Running the .Open on the same RS twice without closing the first is probably whats causing your error)
4. You should escape your input; `replace$(text1.Text, "'", "''")`
5. You should check for `rs.EOF` after the `.open`
6. Use `&` not `+` for concatenating strings

update

```
sub xxx
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sName As String

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\test2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Cn.ConnectionTimeout = 40
Cn.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sName = replace$(text1.Text, "'", "''")
rs.Open "Select * from SampleTable where UserName = '" & sName & "'", Cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

if (rs.eof) then
    msgbox "no match"
else
    TextBox3.Text = rs("UserName") & " " & rs("Location")
    rs.Close
end if

set rs = nothing
Cn.Close
set cn = nothing
end sub
```

Comment: Hi
1. OK
2. uname is because for where clause
3. OK( that was old code.causing Syntax Err )
4. Why? Sorry, not able to understand
5. OK
6. + actually concatenates...It worked.

Comment: (2) You don't need uname like that in the code you posted .. (4) you escape to avoid errors & SQL injection; try to search for ' and see what happens .. (6) & avoids the error + would cause in anint + astring

Comment: uname is used because if I put 

rs.Open "Select * from SampleTable where rs("UserName") = '" & text1.Text & "'", ActiveConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

compiler error is shown for that double quotes...That is why I thought  of using temp variable...but i can't understand  how population of field happens...

could u just take my code lines and edit so that i can copy paste n tell u what problem i face ( if at all I face
)

Comment: If the field name is UserName just use; "Select * from SampleTable where UserName = '" & sName & "'"

Comment: rs.Open "Select * from SampleTable where UserName = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", ActiveConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText; ; ; 

RunTime error 3001

Comment: replace ActiveConnection with Cn in the .open

Comment: Ur Excellent; for integer also i can use the same where clause is it?? with an exception of using Dim sInteger as Integer is it not?? because im not understanding that where clause " " stuff

Comment: If the database field is also numeric you would not escape or quote an integer; `.open "select * from thetable where theNumberField = " & intVariable, Cn, ...`